# second selectbox value changes on first select box change and vice versa

Tags: php, jquery

if i select 1st box second box will get changed and vice versa.

```
echo '<td><select id=hello name=hello onchange=my()>';

while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
echo "<option value=".$fet['username'].">".$fet['username']."</option>";
}
echo '</select></td>';
 echo "<td><div id='myDiv'><select id=id name=id onchange=my1()>";

while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
echo "<option value=".$fet['id'].">".$fet['id']."</option>";
}
echo '</select></div></td>';
```

Comment: please paste onchange js functions

Comment: What exaclty is your question?

Comment: i dont know how to write it.can u help me.

Comment: if i change the category name category id will get selected in second selectbox. if i choose the category id it first select box will get selected relevent categoryname

Comment: Please add some example description in your question to understand your requirements in better way, also post your `my()` and `my1()` javascript function to understand the change you are trying to do

Comment: i didnt write my() my1() function yet now.

Comment: Would it be helpful enough if someone posted an example of how to do this with javascript / jquery and not php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Jquery:
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
       <script>
       $(function(){
      $('#name-first').on('change',function(){
      var selIndex= $("#name-first option:selected").index();
      $("#name-second option").eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
      });
      });
     $(function(){

      $('#name-second').on('change',function(){
      var selIndex= $("#name-second option:selected").index();
      $("#name-first option").eq(selIndex).prop('selected', true);
      });
       });
    </script>

     //select 1

      <select name="cnoption1" id="name-first" onchange=loadXMLDoc()>';
      $op="select * from t_category";
      $op1=mysql_query($op); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($op1))
       {
       echo '<option  value='.$row["categoryname"].'>' .$row["categoryname"].'  </option>';
        }
       echo '</select></div></td>';
       //select 2

       echo '<select name="cioption2" id="name-second" class="InputField">';
        $opt="select * from t_category";
        $opt1=mysql_query($opt); while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($opt1))
        {
         echo '<option  value='.$row1["categoryid"].'> '.$row1["categoryid"].' </option>'; }
         echo  '</select></p></div></td>';
```